# ESS not installable (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ess, install, ubuntu

The day before yesterday, I have experienced my Ubuntu package `ess` (Version: 17.11-3bionic0) no more configuring properly during `apt-get update`.  I then tried `apt-get install -d ess` and:

```
dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/ess_17.11-3bionic0_all.deb
```

I get:

```
Preparing to unpack .../ess_17.11-3bionic0_all.deb ...
Remove ess for emacs25
remove/ess: purging byte-compiled files for emacs25
Unpacking ess (17.11-3bionic0) over (17.11-3bionic0) ...
Setting up ess (17.11-3bionic0) ...
Install emacsen-common for emacs25
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs25
Install ess for emacs25
install/ess: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs25
ERROR: install script from ess package failed
dpkg: error processing package ess (--install):
installed ess package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ess
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNU Emacs 25.2.2.

Looking in the emacs package manager, it says:

```
  ess                17.11         incompat   melpa-s... Emacs Speaks Statistics
```

So, it seems that the package from melpa is uninstallable because of being incompatible with my current Ubuntu emacs version, and the Ubuntu package of the same version can neither be installed.

I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/254815/835198) from Ubuntu SX but it didn't work for me.

What else can I do now?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you try downloading the DEB package without installing it (use `-d` option with `apt-get`) and then install it with `dpkg`? This would give a better error message.

Comment: Did that, does not seem to be much more informative.

Comment: A solution to the problem is posted under "ESS install fails for Ubuntu 18.04".

Comment: I'll have to look at it when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Thx, I just found out.

Comment: just saw you opened a duplicate. I think the problem I posted is essentially the same. My solution is probably only a temporary one.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs SE!  Your post is more of a comment than an answer, so I'm moving it to a comment position on the original question.  After you gain some rep, you will be able to comment directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness.  A look at 
[ESS on GitHub](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/635) or 
[r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2018-August/002942.html)
required me to download:

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/tmp/elpa-ess_17.11-4_all.deb

http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/tmp/ess_17.11-4_all.deb

and to install them via:

```
dpkg -i ess_17.11-4_all.deb elpa-ess_17.11-4_all.deb
```

Works for me on 18.04.

**Edit:** The CRAN repository has been [updated accordingly](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/635#issuecomment-415243045). So, the above procedure is now only needed if you do not want to use the package manager for this.